# RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox

Tags: linux, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Имеется:

```
Firefox == 58.0.2   
selenium == 3.9.0  
geckodriver == 0.19.1  
Python == 3.6.4
Debian based Linux (64bit)
```

`chmod +x`-нутый *geckodriver* в `usr/local/bin`.
Запуская `geckodriver --version` в терминале выдаётся:

> geckodriver 0.19.1
>
> The source code of this program is available from
>   testing/geckodriver in https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central.
>
> This program is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0.
>   You can obtain a copy of the license at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.

Firefox установленный не через apt-get , а разархивированный в `/usr/bin/firefox`

В *.bashrc* файл добавила строчку:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/firefox
```

Когда запускаю нижнее:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap, executable_path="/usr/local/bin")

link = browser.get('https://duckduckgo.com')
web2 = link.find_element_by_class_name('logo_homepage__tt').text
print(web2)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox

Comment: На всякий случай echo $SHELL покажите.

Comment: @defrag, `echo $SHELL` выдаёт `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения есть три пункта:

1. Установка Firefox из репозитория. (<strike>Что мне не подходит</strike>)
2. Указать путь для бинарника Firefox селениуму.
3. Добавить Firefox бинарник в Path.

Для второго пункта:

Чтобы задать путь до Firefox нужно использовать FirefoxBinary в коде:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('/Firefox/Path')
# binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox/firefox') # в моём случае
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Для третьего пункта:

Добавить нижнее в ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/firefox"
```

в моём случае (нужно было именно до файла прописать, а не до папки):

```
было --> export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/firefox    

стало --> export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/firefox/firefox
```

Чтобы узнать где расположен Firefox:
дать команду `which firefox` или `whereis firefox` в терминале.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874857/runtimeerror-could-not-find-firefox-in-your-system-path-please-specify-the-fir/48875147#48875147)